# Is there a way to move a bevel and emboss shape to illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, photoshop-effects

I have made a logo for my husband and son, I need to convert it to illustrator but there is a curved shape that has bevel and emboss from Photoshop that doesn't look the same when I put it in illustrator. Also what size canvas should it be in Photoshop to keep its quality in Illustrator? I have added their logo so you can see the shape I am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Importing this from PS to AI doesn't really come with any direct benefit. You can easily re-work this in Illustrator so you have it in a proper vector format, which will save you alot of time and trouble in the future. The effects you have on the green stripe can easily be replicated in AI.